# Why are there two "woulds" in this sentence?

Tags: difference, usage, will-would

I'm a little bit baffled why there are two "woulds" in this dialogue? Why doesn't speaker B use "will?"

> A: Which sentence is your choice?
>
> 1. If I study hard then I will succeed.
> 2. If I study hard I will then
>    succeed.
> 3. If I study hard I will succeed.
>
> B: They are all grammatically correct. Which one I **would** choose **would** depend on the situation.

Comment: The sentence in question is also grammatically correct, but you **could** say "Which one I would chose **depends** on the situation / context"

Comment: @PeterJennings Could you explain what the use of "woulds" in the sentence?

Comment: Should be "which one I chose" in a traditional analysis, but pairing two "would"s is so common one might as well call it standard.

Comment: In "which one I could choose", *which* is an interrogative determinative, so that entire phrase is a noun phrase with *I would choose* as a defining clause, with the auxiliary verb *will* shifted to *would* because it's a hypothetical (if I were given a choice being implicit).

The second *would* is again shifted from auxiliary *will* to *would* because it's conditional, and *would depend* is the main verb whose subject is the noun-phrase described in the sentence above.

Comment: You don't need *either* of the modals. They're both really just "fillers, hedges". Plain *Which [one] I choose depends on context* is fine. It's splitting hairs to claim that any particular combination of additional ***will**'s* and ***would**'s* could usefully contribute to / modify the meaning, in almost all feasible contexts. They're just ringing the syntactic changes for the sake of variety.

Comment: @TimR Thanks. Is it also acceptable to use "will" in that sentence? *They are all grammatically correct. Which one I **will** choose **will** depend on the situation.*

Comment: @Nyambek A speaker using **will** there expects to have a choice (it is not a hypothetical situation), and is saying that the choice has not already been made. The circumstances at the time will be a consideration.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Thansk a lot. Why does a native speaker always use "would" in their answer? Why not use "will"? Is it unllikely in this case? Could you explain?

Comment: @TimR I'm still confused. You meant "will" is used for something that has been made in this context? What does "will" exactly mean in this case?

Comment: **I'd say** it's a sort of "habit" among Anglophones to sprinkle our utterances with such "hedges". Obviously there's no good *reason* for including the highlighted initial element in my comment here, but it's perfectly natural, especially when ***would*** is abbreviated to ***'d***. On the other hand, if I'd started with ***I will say...*** that might well be perceived as implying I'm reluctant to say everyting that I think (but I'm prepared to say *some* things). And plain ***I say...*** would probably come across as stridently dogmatic.

Comment: I'd also suggest that there's a subtle distinction between how ***then*** works in your example #1 compared to the (*very* "unusual, but still "valid") example #2. In the first, ***then*** primarily implies ***as a consequence*** (a "causality" reference), whereas in #2 it's more like ***afterwards, later*** (a "temporal" reference). But #2 is weird anyway, so you'd best forget it.

Comment: For most native speakers, I'd say, though perhaps not for all, **will** is used with situations that are expected to occur, not with hypotheticals.  A general manager for a football team, for example, might use **will** when referring to the choices he expects to have when acquiring new players for the team. *Who I will choose will depend on the situation.*  But a fan of the team, imagining himself to be in the general manager's shoes, would probably say *Who I would choose would depend on the situation.*

Comment: @TimR: That's all "sorta true", but I'd suggest the increased likelihood of a football team *manager* using ***will*** rather than ***would*** is simply because so many managers of top-level English football teams are non-Anglophone North Europeans. Dutch and Germans (some with otherwise impeccable English) certainly tend to include ***will*** more often than the natives. And I personally would *never* use initial uncontracted *If I **would** have known you were coming, I'd have baked a cake*. But I've had to get used to the fact that Germans (and some Americans) do this all the time.

Comment: @TimR I'm beginning to understand. Another dialgue: A: What's the meaning of "hair off"?

*Dave tries to shoot a kid in car's trunk to lure out Robert from hiding:*

*Dave: I was a **hair off** on that one. I might have hit the kid.*

B: I **willd** / **would** understand it to mean I (or my aim) was out by only a hair’s breadth. In other words, I very nearly shot the kid.

In this context, which should I use "will" or "would?"

Comment: @FumbleFingers But I always see a native speaker say **I would say** and not **I will say**. For instance, someone answers a question from a questioner: *I **would** say xyz there.* Can "will" be used here?

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm saying. We tend to say ***I would say...*** rather than ***I will say...*** If you like, you *can* use ***will*** there (or just baldly assert ***I say** [whatever you think / know is true]*). But just be aware that this might *slightly* mark you out as a non-native speaker. (In the written form, I mean. Obviously in the *spoken* form, you're probably giving out that information far more clearly! :)

Comment: @FumbleFingers Which should I use "will" or "would" when I answer a question? 

**A**: Does "openings" mean chances in this match report?
*Chelsea still dominating the ball so far, but Norwich having a few more openings.*
**B**: I **will** / **would** interpret it as "opportunities."

Comment: It makes little difference, and if you *still* don't have any idea whether to use ***will*** or ***would*** in the example in your immediately preceding comment, the best advice I can give you is to ignore the possibility of learning and understanding the relevant factors here. Just use whichever *you* like, and forget everything else. But you might like to base your choice regarding "whichever you like" on the fact that if **B** is a native Anglophone, he'll most likely say ***I would interpret...***, and least likely say ***I will interpret...*** (with ***I interpret...*** in the middle).

Comment: @FumbleFingers  I think ***I will interpret it as...*** is incorrect because as TimR has explained, **will** is used with situations that are expected to occur. So it doesn't make sense in an answer to a question about what I interpret the word.

Comment: I think you are NOT learning much here! *None* of the 3 alternatives are "incorrect"! Whether you use ***will, would,*** or ***no auxiliary*** is in almost all cases a stylistic choice. The "unusual" contexts where any one of those choices could truly be called "incorrect" are so unlikely it's not worth trying to explain what they are. It seems to me the most important thing for you to learn here is that in many situations it's hopelessly misleading to conflate "less common stylistic choice" with "incorrect".

Comment: @Nyambek: "a hair off" means "inaccurate by the tiniest degree", as you said. If I estimate that something weighs 145 kilos and it actually weighs 144.75 kilos, my estimate is "a hair off". You could say "Normally we use 'a hair off' to refer to missing the mark by a very small distance. But I **would** understand him to be saying that his bullet might have grazed the kid."  There "would" indicates that you are offering a *conjecture*. It is *tentative*.

Comment: The verb "depend" is not an ordinary verb when it comes to using the future tense. "Depends" vs "will depend" vs "would depend" is an individual topic. Google it and you'll see :)

Answer (score 0):

Both "Would"s here are in the *irrealis mood*, which indicates unreal situations, as with *unreal conditionals*.

"*...would choose...*" indicates speaker B doesn't have to choose among those three possibilities.

"*...would depend...*" indicates that nothing depends on the situation because the situation doesn't exist.

Expanded to full unreal conditionals, it might read like this:

> **If I had to choose** which sentence to use from among those three, which one I would choose would depend on the situation.

Using "will" is incorrect both because we cannot use "will" in an *irrealis mood* clause, and because it wouldn't be about the future, even if it were in *realis mood*.